# Visualisation of general 3x3 matrices, with applications to the pedagogy of linear algebra?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, matrix-theory, visualization

I've got a method for visualising non-zero $2 \times 2$ real matrices (modulo non-zero scalar factor) using the fact that:

- Nonnegative determinant matrices (modulo non-zero scalar factor) are in 1-to-1 correspondence with hyperbolic cycles in the hyperbolic plane, endowed with orientation
- Nonpositive determinant matrices (modulo non-zero scalar factor) are in 1-to-1 correspondence with "pencils of lines of equal inclination" in the hyperbolic plane

The significance is that this depicts:

- The eigenvalues of a matrix
- Its eigenvectors
- Its condition number
- Its Jordan normal form
- What it's orthogonally similar to
- Whether it is diagonal
- Or upper triangular
- Or lower triangular
- Or symmetric
- Or orthogonal

The question arises: Are there other methods for visualising *general* matrices, which convey properties *which are significant for linear algebra*? I'm especially interested in techniques valid for $3 \times 3$ matrices.

[Ask on MSE? Don't ask anywhere?]

Comment: You might be interested in https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02131

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky Interestingly, my approach isn't mentioned